# Can't Use combobox in C# code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, combobox

I want to add itens to a combobox but in c# because i dont want to add all the time the same comboboxitens. My code is this to the combobox i want to add itens.

```
    <ScrollViewer Margin="252,130,296,134" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled">
            <StackPanel >
                <ItemsControl x:Name="ic" Grid.Row="2">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="#C83245" Background="White"  BorderThickness="1">
                                        <ComboBox x:Name="cbSeletion" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Width="250" Height="40" Foreground="Black" Tapped="cbSeletion_Tapped">

                                        </ComboBox>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="#C83245" Background="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="350" Foreground="Black"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="#C83245" Background="White"  BorderThickness="1" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Foreground="Black"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

what can i do to use it?

Comment: Create an Items ViewModel for your ItemsControl and have the Collection of data items in there. Then bind your ComboBox.ItemsSource to the collection of each Item.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the combobox ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection in your viewmodel:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

The property:

```
ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
     get
     {
          return _items;
     }
}
```

You can then add items to and from that collection and the items in the dropdown will reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have really few items, you could directly use the `ComboBoxItem` in XAML, but still it is not that ellegant. The MVVM approach is definately the answer, especially for many items in the collection of the ComboBox, cause it gives you greater flexibility and the logic is not that hard-coded.

Comment: I add the comboboxitem and cant use it too